# Is there a faster way to perform this neighbour finding operation

Tags: python, autocorrelation

I'm trying to calculate Moran's I in Python ([This is the underlying equation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-spatial-autocorrelation-moran-s-i-spatial-st.htm)). My inputs are a coords Nx3 array containing the coordinates of each point and a Nx3 array z which contains the values minus the overall mean. The operation requires each value of z to be multiplied with every point within a set distance (here set to 1.99). My problem is that in my case N=~2 Million and so the find_neighbours operation is very slow. Is there a way I could speed this up?

```
def find_neighbours(coords,idx,k):
   distances = np.sqrt(np.power(coords - coords[idx], 2).sum(axis=1))
   distances[idx] = np.inf
   return np.argwhere(distances<=k)

z   = x - np.mean(x)
n   = len(coords)
A   = 0
B   = np.sum([z[idx]**2 for idx,coord in enumerate(coords)])
S_0 = 0

for idx in range(len(coords)):
    neighbours = find_neighbours(coords,idx,1.99)
    S_0 += len(neighbours)
    A += np.sum([(z[neighbour]*z[idx]) for neighbour in neighbours])
    
I = (n/S_0)*(A/B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical problem with plenty of literature about. It's called ***Radius Neighbor Search in Three-dimensional Point Clouds*** . You need to store your points in a better data structure to do the search faster. I would suggest an *octree*.

Check python code [here](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/blob/master/examples/official/octree/octree_search.py) and adapt to your case.

For explanations, check [this](https://jbehley.github.io/papers/behley2015icra.pdf) paper.